# Using the Facebook SDKs WebView to show custom web page?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, webview

I'm wondering if it's possible to use Facebooks Android SDK to open up a Facebook WebView but instead of showing facebook related stuff I wanna show my custom page which is using Facebook Comments Social Plugin.

The reason? I wanna make use of the cookies that are stored in that WebView so that a user doesn't need to login again if he's already been logged in. And in the case that he's not logged in, he can login using the SDKs Login Flow.

Is any of this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: The Facebook SDK only loads WebView if the application is not installed on the device. Anyway, I guess that with reflection you could... maybe.

Comment: Yah but you should be able to show a WebView directly using the SDK even if the facebook app is installed, is it not? :o

Comment: That I am not sure, sorry.

Comment: The SDK handles this and decides whether to show the WebView or fast-switch to the Facebook for Android.